# Why the following code block is giving output "ZZZ(some garbage value)" instead of "ZZ(some garbage value)"

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, memory-address

On printing the &a (`cout<<&a`), compiler is giving output 'Z' but when we print character before printing character address it gives output(`cout<<a<<" "<<&a`) as 'Z ZZ'. I know that cout treats character address differently i.e on getting an address of character it doesn't print that address instead it prints the contents which are there at that address. Please help me with the concept i am missing here. Here is the code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    char a = 'Z';
    cout<<a<<&a;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Let me ask you, Why can't the third `Z` be a garbage value?

Comment: @NathanOliver the third Z can't be a garbage value because i have tried both cout<<&a; and cout<<a<<&a; in a same program multiple times.  Moreover &a should give same output in both statements since both will be having same garbage value.

Comment: I'm not getting the "garbage values" you get. https://onlinegdb.com/r1Znrc49S

Comment: You're trying to anticipate undefined behaviour. This is futile by definition.

Comment: just because you see the same output multiple times does not mean that there is a guarantee for it. undefined behaviour is just undefined, aka anything can happen

Comment: @smac89 Why it is different here https://ideone.com/2fO74o and in my local compiler.

Comment: Because it's undefined behaviour. Anything can happen.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 What is exaclty undefined here?

Comment: Trying to print a `char` as if it was a string.

Comment: it is undefined what output your code generates. Not only starting from the third character, but all of it is undefined. You make `cout` read from memory you shouldn't

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
char a = 'Z';
cout << &a;
```

This treats the address of `a` as an address to a null terminated string and prints this string. Since that is not a pointer to a null terminated string (it's a pointer to a single `char`) you have Undefined Behavior in your program.

Undefined Behavior means that the program doesn't have a defined behavior, i.e. it can have any behavior: it can print garbage, it can print other garbage, it can print nothing, it can crash or pretty much any behavior.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to output the address of the variable `a` then write

```
char a = 'Z';
cout << a << static_cast<void *>( &a );
```

Otherwise the compiler tries to output a string pointed to by the expression `&a` that has the type `char *` until the zero-terminating character is encountered.

Thus this output

```
cout << &a;
```

has undefined behavior.

If you want to output the variable a as an array having a string then you have to declare an array instead of the scalar variable and initialize it with a string literal instead of the character literal. For example

```
char a[] = "Z";
cout << *a << &a;
```

Comment: make worth mentioning (more explicitly) that the character array is null terminated